# Django query with two Foreign keys - check if exist, assign or create

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a Car dealer app - When a user selecting a car/vehicle, they must select a make, and model in that order. The preferred behaviour would be to cascade each lookup selection as a filter to the next lookup. When a user changes a master lookup (Make), child lookup should be cleared and updated - Model of a vehicle/car

I will add vehicles via Django shell query manually, but I don't know, how to ensure, that when for example Make of vehicle does not exist, that DB will create it. And later, when I will be adding another car/vehicle, which Make already exists in DB, it is needed that only FK of ID will be assigned to the new record, and no one entry will be created for Make

For example, When first I will add a car with Make of "BMW" and another one will be also "BWM" - so there will not be duplicate records in Make table.

Expected result in DB is:

```
Make      Model     Vehicle
----      ------     -------
BMW  ---- X6    ---- 2018, AAA
     |--- 535i  ---- 2020, BBB
     |--- i8    ---- 2011, CCC

Audi ---- A6    ---- 2020, DDD
     |--- Q7    ---- 2019, EEE

Ford ---- Raptor --- 2018, FFF
```

Here is my project:

**models.py:**

```
class Make(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Model(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=17)
    engine= models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I tried to create a diagram at dbdiagram.io, here is a link: https://dbdiagram.io/d/5f198436e586385b4ff7a6f0

Then I am trying to add via Django shell a record:

```
from catalog.models import Make, Model, Vehicle

v = Vehicle(make=Make(name='BMW'),
          model=Model(name='X6'),
          year=2018,
          vin='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
          engine='3.0L 4',)
v.save()
```

But I am getting ValueError:

> ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved
> related object 'make'.

I am not really convinced if I am doing this right.

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what's happening

```
v = Vehicle(make=Make(name='BMW'),
      model=Model(name='X6'),
      year=2018,
      vin='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      engine='3.0L 4',)
```

at this point, you have created a `Make` object and assigned it to the vehicle, *but it has not been stored in the database yet*.  (That is why Django is complaining about data loss.)  So you would probably want to do this as a first cut:

```
bmw = Make(name='BMW')
bmw.save()

x6 = Model(name='X6', make=bmw) # note use of object
x6.save()

v = Vehicle(make=bmw, model=x6, year=2018...)
v.save()
```

**UPDATE**: in response to the comment below, the next refinement would be use the `get_or_create()` method for the Make and Model objects.

```
bmw, created = Make.object.get_or_create(name='BMW')

x6, created = Model.objects.get_or_create(
    name='X6', make=bmw) # note use of object

v = Vehicle(make=bmw, model=x6, year=2018...)
v.save()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is inserting data to DB, but it duplicates Makes and Models when I create a new record. For example, when I change a data for a second Vehicle and keep Make of "BMW", a new "BMW" make is created and not assigned to the existing one.